# MongoDb - And operation inside arrays inside embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have countries in a mongoDB collection. An example of a country document is the following:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "cities": [
        {
            "_id": ObbjectId("..."),
            "neighborhoods": [
                {
                    "_id": ObbjectId("..."),
                    "schools": 5,
                    "stadiums": [
                        {
                            "_id": ObbjectId("...")
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": ObbjectId("...")
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObbjectId("..."),
                    "schools": 3,
                    "stadiums": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObbjectId("..."),
            "neighborhoods": [
                {
                    "_id": ObbjectId("..."),
                    "schools": 1,
                    "stadiums": []
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObbjectId("..."),
                    "schools": 5,
                    "stadiums": [
                        {
                            "_id": ObbjectId("...")
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": ObbjectId("...")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is the query to get all the countries that have at least one city that has at least 1 neighborhood with the stadiums collection empty and the schools equals to 1?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) together to build the query.

Something like

```
db.col.find({cities:{$elemMatch:{neighborhoods:{$elemMatch:{schools:1,stadiums:[]}}}}})
```